# error: to be read again \relax

Tags: tables, tabularx, pgfplotstable

Here is my code for the tabular environment and I got the same error as mention in title.

```
\usepackage{caption}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering}m{#1}}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}





\begin{center}
 \captionof{table}
 \begin{tabular}{|p{2.3cm}||p{2cm}|}
 \hline
 \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Parameter of GA} \\
 \hline
 Parameters   & value \\
 \hline
 Maximum iteration &\rmfamily  200 \\
 Population size &\rmfamily 30\\
 $P_{c}$&\rmfamily 0.9 \\
 $P_{m}$ &\rmfamily 0.1\\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: `\captionof{table}{caption}`. You forgot the caption part.

Comment: Oh!!! I just forgot it. Thank you Torbjorn.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of a syntax error (omitted caption argument) identified in the comments and confirmed by the op.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. -- to make this useful for some later visitor, please add an answer; can still be closed.